# Using conditional if in react

Tags: react.js

I have the following code working fine:

`rowData` is an object and I want to display download button only if the `completePathName` is not null and hence I did the following which is working fine. I am wondering if I can improve the following code in some manner or the conditional if that I have used is fine?

```
buttonTemplate = (rowData: any, column: any)  => {
        //if(typeof rowData !=='undefined' && typeof rowData.completePathName !=='undefined'){
        if(rowData.completePathName === null){
            return (
            
              console.log("Inside first return  - testing rowData:"),
              console.log(rowData),
              console.log(rowData.completePathName),
                <div style={{textAlign: 'center', width: '6em'}}>
                        <span>
                            <Button type='button' icon="pi pi-pencil" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(rowData, e)} tooltip='Edit'/>
                            <Button icon="pi pi-trash" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} tooltip='Delete' />
                            
                        </span>
                </div>
            );

        }
        else {
            return (
                
                console.log("Inside second return  - testing rowData:"),
                console.log(rowData),
                console.log(rowData.completePathName),
            
                <div style={{textAlign: 'center', width: '6em'}}>
                        <span>
                            <Button type='button' icon="pi pi-pencil" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(rowData, e)} tooltip='Edit'/>
                            <Button icon="pi pi-trash" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} tooltip='Delete' />
                            <Button icon="pi pi-download" tooltip='Download' />
                            
                        </span>
                </div>
            );

        }
       
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing that changes in the JSX is the download button, so it'd be more appropriate to use [conditional rendering](https://reactjs.org/docs/conditional-rendering.html) when the JSX comes to that line to decide whether you need to render the last button or not:

```
const ButtonTemplate = (rowData: any) => (
    <div style={{textAlign: 'center', width: '6em'}}>
        <span>
            <Button type='button' icon="pi pi-pencil" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} onClick={(e) => this.handleClick(rowData, e)} tooltip='Edit'/>
            <Button icon="pi pi-trash" style={{marginRight: '5px'}} tooltip='Delete' />
            {
              rowData.completePathName !== null &&
              <Button icon="pi pi-download" tooltip='Download' />
            }
        </span>
    </div>
);
```

Other notes:

- Since you don't use the `column` parameter, you should remove it entirely
- Using `any` defeats the whole point of using TypeScript, since it effectively disables type-checking for that expression - if you can give proper types to things, it'll make your life a whole lot easier. Consider figuring out how you can type `rowData`. It may look something like:

  ```
  rowData: {
    completePathName: string | null
  }
  ```

  (or something similar - just for an example)
- If you want to be able to call this as a *component*, give it an upper-case name: `ButtonTemplate`, not `buttonTemplate`. That'll let you do

  ```
  <ButtonTemplate {...{ rowData, column }} />
  ```

  to render it.
- You have a lot of inline styles, which makes the JSX harder to read. Consider separating out the style into CSS instead. With Sass, you could give the container a class of `buttons-container`, and then do:

  ```
  .buttons-container {
      text-align: center;
      width: 6em;
      button:not([tooltip="Download"]) {
          margin-right: 5px;
     }
  }
  ```

  and remove **all** the inline styles from the JSX.